# What does Fsync do on MPU6050?

Tags: microcontroller, imu, 6050

I'm looking to use the 6050 IMU and I am confused on what Fsync does, is it controlled by the host or the MPU 6050 itself?

https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf

If I want to synchronize capture to an external trigger can I do it with Fsync? Or does Fsync a control signal instead?

In my particular application I have a global shutter camera and I want to sample IMU at 10x the cameras capture rate. Can I use Fsync to do this? Or would Fsync be used as a clock on the MCU?

Answer (score 1):

I have no direct experience, and the [datasheet](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf) doesn't say much about it. It's definitely an input to the MPU-6050.

It doesn't appear to affect the operation of the chip; but its value can be copied into the internal FIFO along with the sensor data. Presumably, this allows the host software to determine which samples came before or after a change of state of the FSYNC pin. This allows the data to be correlated with external events.

Comment: Your guess is correct. That is indeed the purpose of that pin - at least anytime I saw it actually used for something. It's not widely used perhaps, but if you need it, then not having it is a major pain.